# how to add md5sum value for csv file using awk

Tags: awk, hashsum

I have csv file as mentioned below format,

```
1,123-456,IND
2,234-567,US
3,345-678,AUS
4,333-444,SA
```

I don't want to use any loops, I want to generate md5sum value for each row using AWK command as mentioned below output format,

```
1,123-456,IND,<md5 value>
2,234-567,US,<md5 value>
3,345-678,AUS,<md5 value>
4,333-444,SA,<md5 value>
```

Comment: i have not used external command , can you help me

Comment: using for loop I am able to get the result ,but  I want to try with awk command

Comment: What is it you want the md5 value of? The whole file, each line of the file, a specific field on each line or something else?

Comment: each line md5 value

Comment: Should the hashes treat the whole line (including the comma separators) as a string, or do you want a hash of the concatenated field values alone?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't involve awk in this at all, I'd just use the shell directly, but [you said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616648/how-to-add-md5sum-value-for-csv-file-using-awk#comment1153364_616648) "I want to try with awk command" so I assume you have a good reason:

```
awk -v OFS=',' '{
    cmd = "echo \047" $0 "\047 | md5sum"
    val = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "FAILED")
    close(cmd)
    sub(/ .*/,"",val)
    print $0, val
}' file
1,123-456,IND,df6c21260b315d90fbbb6da2969b721c
2,234-567,US,764fd46b443bb125e48f154f964ee1d7
3,345-678,AUS,3b769d86ef698ca08de9dccabe402f02
4,333-444,SA,345b7e3e29df314844a7625e5b6e3486
```

The above assumes each line doesn't contain anything that your version of echo could mangle.

Comment: Awesome! I figured there was likely some way to invoke a Linux command but wasn't sure how to grab the output.

Comment: Please see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline if you're going to be using `getline` and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next with this question.

Comment: @Ed Morton this is working fine but its running too slow

Comment: Of course it's slow. You should be calling md5sum directly from shell but instead from shell you're calling awk to, for every line of input, spawn a subshell to call md5sum. You should be doing `shell { md5sum }` but instead you're doing `shell { awk { system { shell { md5sum } } } }`. This **IS** how you do it using awk as you requested though. If you want to learn how do it without using awk then accept this answer as it's the correct answer to the question you asked (`how to add md5sum value for csv file using awk`) and then ask a new question.

Comment: can we have any alternative solution to get results in faster using Unix

Comment: Yes, call md5sum directly from shell as previously mentioned. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do wrt this question and then post a new question asking about that if you want to learn how to do that.