# pattern check in using AWK command

Tags: text-processing, awk, regular-expression

I have csv file as mentioned below format.

```
1,123-456,IND,91,UAE,97,USA,01,SA,27
3,345-678,AUS,61,SLA,94,NZW,64,RS,7
```

it should check based on `,(\w{3}),(\d{2}),` pattern check  and how many times its matching it should show in `|` delimited as mentioned below, using AWK command how to achieve.

expected output

```
1,123-456,IND,91|UAE,97|USA,01
3,345-678,AUS,61|SLA,94|NZW,64
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind editing your post to indicate what you already tried? Otherwise contributors might suggest a solution that you already know won't work.

Comment: The second line should be `3,345-678,AUS,61|SLA,94|NZW,64`, right?

Comment: Does it have to be awk? It is much easier in other tools. Also, why is the `SA, 27` disappearing in your output?

Comment: @terdon, "SA" is only 2 chars, not 3

Comment: Note that GNU awk implements `\w` but not `\d` for some reason. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html

Comment: @glennjackman OK, so are we supposed to remove those? What if we have something like `,IND,91,SA,27,UAE,97,USA,01`?

Comment: Then I would expect the output to be `,IND,91|UAE,97|USA,01` but @rambo needs to help us out.

Comment: Do you REALLY want an awk solution or are you going to ask for a different solution after getting the awk solution like in [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/616648/133219)?

Answer (score 2):

When you say `\w+`, I assume you actually mean `[a-zA-Z]` since `\w` also matches numbers and underscores and it looks like you only want letters. In fact, based on your example, you might only want capital letters. Finally, and again I'm guessing here since you don't explain, it looks like you want to exclude cases where the letters string is not exactly 3 characters long. If so, here's a way of doing what you want in Perl:

```
$ perl -lne '/^(.*?),[A-Z]{3},\d{2},/; $start=$1; @k=(/,(\w{3},\d{2})/g); print "$start,", join("|",@k)' file
1,123-456,IND,91|UAE,97|USA,01
3,345-678,AUS,61|SLA,94|NZW,64
```

Alternatively, and assuming you only want to make the matches after the 2nd field, you can do this in awk:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="," '{
                        for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=2){
                        if ($i~/^[A-Z]{3}$/ && $(i+1)~/^[0-9]{2}$/){
                            k ? k=k"|"$i","$(i+1) : k=$i","$(i+1); 
                        }
                       } print $1,$2,k; k=""}' file
1,123-456,IND,91|UAE,97|USA,01
3,345-678,AUS,61|SLA,94|NZW,64
```